# GeoPandas not recognizing geometry type

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, valueerror

I am trying to write a point in polygon spatial join to file by county. In my code I read in a GeoJSON object of building polygons for a whole state, grab the centroid and split the centroid points by the states counties before writing them to file. The code works and does what I ask it to for the first state but then breaks when the state finishes and moves on to the next in a loop. Is there another way to do this? Should I set my geometry explicitly after each county loop? I have checked to make sure every geometry in the GeoPandas geometry column was a point but I am still receiving this error message: `"ValueError:Geometry column cannot contain mutiple geometry types when writing to file."`

```
import geopandas as gpd
import geopandas as gpd
#from fiona.crs import from_epsg
import pandas as pd
import time
import os

footprint_dir = 'D:\Data Repository\GIS Data\Building_Footprint\\'
county_dir = 'D:\Data Repository\GIS Data\Census_Shapefiles\County\\'

states = ['AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'ID', 'NM', 'OR', 'TX', 'UT', 'WA']
state_names = ['Arizona', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Idaho', 'NewMexico', 
'Oregon', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Washington']

states = ['ID']
state_names = ["Idaho"]
counter = 0
t0 = time.time()
for state in state_names:
    directory = footprint_dir + states[counter] + '\\'
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

    footprint_fn = footprint_dir + state + '.geojson'
    footprint_gdf = gpd.read_file(footprint_fn)
    county_fn = county_dir + states[counter] + '_Counties\\' + 
    states[counter] + '_Counties.shp'
    shape = gpd.read_file(county_fn)
    shape.crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'}
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(footprint_gdf, geometry = 'geometry', crs = 
        {'init' :'epsg:4326'})
    gdf_centroids = gdf.centroid
    df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(len(gdf_centroids)),
               'geometry': gdf_centroids})
    points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry', crs = {'init' : 
        'EPSG:4326'})
    pointInPolys = gpd.sjoin(points, shape, how='left', op='within')
    pointInPolys = pointInPolys.dropna(thresh=2)
    pointInPolys.crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'}
    pointInPolys.set_geometry(col = 'geometry', inplace=True)
    #pointInPolys.geom_type = 'Point'
    for county in pointInPolys.GEOID.unique():
        countyfile = pointInPolys[pointInPolys.GEOID == county]
        output_fn = directory + states[counter] + "_" + str(county)
        countyfile.crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'}
        countyfile.to_file(output_fn)
        print(output_fn)
    counter += 1
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-6606253fd504> in <module>()
     39         output_fn = directory + states[counter] + "_" + str(county)
     40         countyfile.crs = {'init' :'epsg:4326'}
---> 41         countyfile.to_file(output_fn)
     42         print(output_fn)
     43     counter += 1

D:\Anaconda\envs\raster_processing\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py in to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, **kwargs)
    363         """
    364         from geopandas.io.file import to_file
--> 365         to_file(self, filename, driver, schema, **kwargs)
    366 
    367     def to_crs(self, crs=None, epsg=None, inplace=False):

D:\Anaconda\envs\raster_processing\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py in to_file(df, filename, driver, schema, **kwargs)
     58     """
     59     if schema is None:
---> 60         schema = infer_schema(df)
     61     filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(filename))
     62     with fiona.drivers():

D:\Anaconda\envs\raster_processing\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py in infer_schema(df)
     88     geom_type = _common_geom_type(df)
     89     if not geom_type:
---> 90         raise ValueError("Geometry column cannot contain mutiple "
     91                          "geometry types when writing to file.")
     92 

ValueError: Geometry column cannot contain mutiple geometry types when writing to file.
```

Comment: Also for some reason geopandas is not saving the output coordinate reference system. It populates an empty .prj file with 0 kb size.

Answer (score 1):

a lot going on here, but to start you can make points and reproject in a simpler way...instead of initializing new GDFs to get to points:

```
footprint_gdf = gpd.read_file(footprint_fn) 
footprint_gdf.geometry = footprint_gdf.centroid
```

you can check that the CRS is what you want like so:

```
if footprint_gdf.crs != {'init' :'epsg:4326'}: # this will re-project only if necessary
    footprint_gdf.to_crs({'init' :'epsg:4326'}, inplace=True)
```

now you have `footprint_gdf` == `points` that you are using in the `sjoin`, without all the extra intermediate DFs.

Without the files, my guess is that you're picking up NULL geometries because the filter that you've set isn't stringent enough here:

```
pointInPolys = pointInPolys.dropna(thresh=2)
```

I'm not sure how many columns end up in the `pointInPolys` DF, but if `geometry` is the only column that is NULL it will be kept through the above statement, which probably isn't what you want. I'd look there first. you can use `subset` keyword to just drop NULL values in the geometry column like so:

```
pointInPolys = pointInPolys.dropna(subset=['geometry'])
```

Also, make sure that when you are projecting a DF you use the `to_crs` method and not an assignment like you do in your code. This changes the CRS without adjusting all of the geometries in it!